# Compare matching entries in large data frames

Tags: r

Suppose I have two data frames with the following general structure:

```
A=data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,6, 10), Obs=c(0,5,6,7,3,-4))
B=data.frame(ID=c(1,3,2,4,8), Obs=c(10,-5,NA,7,NA))
```

For matching ID's I want to report:

- Entries in A that are NA's in B, or
- Entries for which the sign on the column "Obs" flips.

There are, however, a couple of complications:

- Some IDs are not unique. They are also not ordered.
- Not all ID's exist in both data frames, and the data frames are not the same length.
- If IDs are not unique, but the Obs. in that row is 0, the comparison should be run against the row with the non-zero obs.
- Some entries are NA's.

So far, using R, I've parsed the data frames using a loop and IF-statements. E.g. some of my code would look something like this:

```
results.signflip <- data.frame()
results.missingvalue <- data.frame()
Intersection.ID<- intersect(A$ID, B$ID)

for (idx.row in 1:length(Intersection.ID)) {
 idx.selection.A   <- grep(paste0("^", Intersection.ID[idx.row]), A$ID)
 idx.selection.B   <- grep(paste0("^", Intersection.ID[idx.row]), B$ID)

 if ( sign(!A[idx.row, "Obs"] == sign(B[idx.row, "Obs"] )) 
   results.signflip <- rbind(results.signflip, A[idx.row,])

 (... more IF statements...)

}
```

This is obviously a simple and not very efficient way to tackle this problem. Trouble is, the file has some 70.000 entries, and the script runs for hours.

So, my question is: does anyone have a smart idea for some really efficient code?

Comment: Please provide your desired output per the provided data sets.

Comment: What if there are **n** entries in **A** and **k** entries in **B** with same ID, **n** times **k** compares?

Comment: Two clarifications: (1) Desired output is a list of entries that meet the two conditions listed above; (2) if multiple entries with non-zero Obs. exist, use the first one to test the conditions.

Comment: A had one observation with ID of 10, B has none. This means B has a NA or we can throw out all observations with ID=10?

Comment: @Pafnucy: Yes, if an ID only occurs in one data frame, it can be thrown out. That's why in the pseudo-code I first create Intersection.ID, and loop through that.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```
C <- merge(A, B, by = "ID")
C$switch <- sign(C$Obs.x * C$Obs.y)
aggregate(switch ~ ID, C[C$switch != 0 | is.na(C$switch),], head, n = 1, na.action = identity)
#  ID switch
#1  1      1
#2  2     NA
#3  3     -1
```

Some specifics may still have to be adjusted, but they make the question too broad for my taste and the general idea of merging should help you enough to move forward.

Comment: sequence of steps close to: A <- na.omit(A) then merge, get all rows that have NA in B-column as part of solution, 2nd part of solution is leftover data filtered by *C$Obs.x * C$Obs.y < 0* condition

Comment: This is a great solution. Very fast. Thanks!